# Append a child in HTML directly from nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, express

I am making a chat app that requires a user to select a room based on the rooms available in `<datalist>` options, which gets its `<option>`s from server's sql table.

I have a login.html file that asks user to enter a username and room number they want to enter. Initially, it has a datalist, but doesn't have any options inside it.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html");
});
```

I want that before sending login.html upon request, i have the options appended inside the datalist.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    //do something so that options get added in the datalist of my html.
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html");
});
```

Here is the form that is showed in login.html

```
<form id = "myForm2" method = "POST" action = "/user">
    <input type = "text" name = "username" autocomplete = "off" placeholder = "username"><br>
    <input type = "text" name = "roomnum" autocomplete = "off" placeholder = "room number" list = "room_list"><br>

    <datalist id = "room_list">
    </datalist>

     <input type = "submit">
</form>
```

Comment: How about using templating, like Jade or EJS, and stop serving static .html files.

Comment: Isnt there a way to sort of appendChild("newly created option node") directly from server...it is possible though login.html's javascript, is it not through server ?

Comment: No, you can't append anything to a static file on the server, then you'd have to do it on the clientside etc. Installing and using for instance EJS, and passing something to the file and then creating the elements dynamically is not that hard.

Comment: Yep, use templates. Look at Pug (ex Jade), it's easy and quick to learn. If you need help, ping me back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use file system from node https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html will help you. You need to require the "fs" module first.